# Why is this giving me a 0 on my 3rd if statement?

Tags: javascript

I keep getting a 0 when I put this code into REPL in my 3rd if statement. No one seems to be able to figure it out around me. Can you see what's wrong with it?

```
 var humanReadable = function (seconds){
      var sec = 0;
      var min = 0;
      var hr = 0;

      sec = seconds % 60;
      min = parseInt((seconds / 60) % 60);
      hr = parseInt( seconds / 3600 );

      if(sec<10){
        sec = "0"+sec;
      }
      if(min<10){
        min = "0"+min;
      }
      if(hr<10){
        min = "0"+hr;
      }
      console.log(hr + ":" + min + ":" + sec);
    };

humanReadable(0) // '00:00:00'
humanReadable(5) // '00:00:05'
humanReadable(60) // '00:01:00'
humanReadable(86399) // '23:59:59'
humanReadable(359999) // '99:59:59
```

Comment: Why are you changing `min` when `hr` is less than 10?

Comment: Also those calls to `parseInt()` should probably be calls to `Math.floor()` instead..

Comment: All your examples seem to return fine, what's the problem?

Comment: @dippas https://repl.it/languages/javascript Read Eval Print Loop ... basically an interactive console

Answer (score 4):

I believe you have a typo in your function:

```
if(hr<10){
  min = "0"+hr; // should be hr = "0"+hr
}
```

Comment: If the issue is indeed a typo, the question should be closed, not answered...

Comment: @FelixKling wasnt aware that I had enough rank to vote close ... figured I would help the guy out in the mean time

Answer (score 0):

The body of your third if statement should be: `hr = "0"+hr;` I also added semicolons to your function calls.

Run your updated code below and you'll see that it produces your desired output.

```js
var humanReadable = function (seconds)
{
  var sec = 0;
  var min = 0;
  var hr = 0;

  sec = seconds % 60;
  min = parseInt((seconds / 60) % 60);
  hr = parseInt( seconds / 3600 );

  if(sec<10)
  {
    sec = "0"+sec;
  }
  if(min<10)
  {
    min = "0"+min;
  }
  if(hr<10)
  {
    hr = "0"+hr;
  }
  console.log(hr + ":" + min + ":" + sec);
};

humanReadable(0); // '00:00:00'
humanReadable(5); // '00:00:05'
humanReadable(60); // '00:01:00'
humanReadable(86399); // '23:59:59'
humanReadable(359999); // '99:59:59'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if(hr<10){
        min = "0"+hr;
}
```

is what you have

it should be

```
if(hr<10){
        hr = "0"+hr;
}
```